# Occasional HTTP Bad Gateway responses to PowerAutomate in Delete List Items

Tags: list, power-automate, internal-server-error

I inherited a PowerAutomate flow that takes rows out of an Excel table in SharePoint and loads them into a List. An early step in the process is to delete all the existing list items, via the standard Get Items - Apply to Each - Delete Item pattern. Every couple of weeks, it fails on one of the Delete Items (even though the List is empty when I get the support ticket). There are 600 items in this list and there are a handful of lists that we refresh with similar processes at about the same time.

> BadRequest. Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits

The task shows this error:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Item Not Found\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\r\nserviceRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

If I drill down into the 1 retry that occurred, I get a different error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits."
  }
}
```

The 404 confuses me: the item was there moments ago when the Get Items task ran, and it's at like 4 AM so nobody should be in the list messing with it.

This then stops the flow, without reloading the new items. I know I can modify the flow to keep going, but I'd rather not do that because the error handling is rather broad. The only thing I can think of is that it's an issue with number of requests happening at once.

What is the cause of this error and how do I stop it from happening? Or recover gracefully?

Comment: Did you add concurrency in apply to each loop action?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Concurrency is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mainly because of the number of delete requests happing in a minute. If you have enabled parallelization in the **apply to each** of the delete step, turn it off.

Comment: Is this a per-flow delete rate, or is it likely account-wide? I'm told we have several similar jobs kicking off about the same time of the day.

Comment: SharePoint is throttling the delete api calls since it received a lot of delete request in a single minute, this will not affect any other operations happening in any other flows under the same account